# Where is the "Paint Flashing Tool" in Firefox ~84?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Many older blog posts and the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Paint_Flashing_Tool) mention that Firefox has a debug tool to highlight painted areas.

I'm running Firefox version 84, and I cannot find this brush symbol anywhere:

[image]

Am I overlooking something, or does the tool no longer exist in recent Firefox versions?

Comment: For newer versions (~96), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70836269/14070872)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For more recent versions of Firefox (~96), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70839748/14070872). TL;DR - [Paint flashing is gone since the move to WebRender](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1743310), where [paint layers is not a concept](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1612922).

The rest of this answer is true for Firefox ~84, as asked in this question.

---

It still exists but you first have to enable it via the settings. Inside the DevTools press <kbd>F1</kbd> or click the three dots at the right side of the tools and click *Settings*.

[image: Enabling the toolbar button for the paint flashing tool]

Once you've enabled it, a new toolbar button with a stylized paint brush icon will appear in the toolbar. Clicking it, enables the paint flashing tool.

Though note that this tool doesn't seem to work [when WebRender is enabled](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Platform/GFX/WebRender_Where) (new [rendering engine in Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/the-whole-web-at-maximum-fps-how-webrender-gets-rid-of-jank/)), see [bug 1612922](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1612922).

Comment: Shame this is gone, I hope they will add it back.